# How to partition and get only latest records in spark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

i have a spark dataframe df

```
vehicle_coalesce  vehicleNumber  productionNumber pin  checkDate
V123              V123           P123             null 27/08/2023 01:03
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           P234             null 27/08/2023 01:03
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
P456              null           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:03
v456              V456           null             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
V456              V456           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
```

i have to group by vehicleNumber or productionNumber or pin and partition by vehicleNumber or productionNumber of pin and pick only latest records based on latest checkDate

required output is:

```
vehicle_coalesce  vehicleNumber  productionNumber pin  checkDate
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
P123              null           P123             W123 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
V234              V234           null             W234 27/08/2023 01:05
v456              V456           null             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
V456              V456           P456             W456 27/08/2023 01:05
```

here since V123 vehicle has same productionNumber it grouped by it and picked latest records, and for V234 since it has same vehicleNumber it grouped by it and picked latest records and for V456 since it has same pin it grouped by it and picked latest records

how to get it using pyspark

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a groupBy and aggregate on the maximum `checkDate`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ts_join = (
    df
    .groupby('productionNumber')
    .agg(F.max('checkDate').alias('checkDate'))
    .select('productionNumber', 'checkDate')
)

df.join(ts_join, on=['productionNumber', 'checkDate'])
```